# how to create list of list in python constructor

Tags: python, class

I am trying to create list of list using different functions inside the class by calling an constructor array but it is giving one list

I want to specifically use build and build1 both the functions

```
class Sample:
   def __init__(self):
        self.add = list()

   def build(self,name):
        self.add.append(name)

   def build1(self,loc):
        self.add.append(loc)


s = Sample()
a1 = ["mohan,ps","gandhi,as"]
for a in a1:
    split_values = a.split(",")
    s.build(split_values[0])
    s.build1(split_values[1])

print s.add
```

Output

```
['mohan', 'ps', 'gandhi', 'as']
```

**expected output:**

```
[['mohan', 'ps'],['gandhi', 'as']]
```

How to get results as expected output

Comment: `[x.split(",") for x in a1]` should do the trick

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I don't believe this is a duplicate. OP wants to use the two function they specified. It's less about splitting the values than it is about creating a list of lists through a Class.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre  this is not duplicate question

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
class Sample:
   def __init__(self):
        self.add = list()

   def build(self,name):
        self.add.append(name)

   def build1(self,loc):
        self.add[-1].append(loc)     #Use negative index to append.


s = Sample()
a1 = ["mohan,ps","gandhi,as"]
for a in a1:
    split_values = a.split(",")
    s.build([split_values[0]])
    s.build1(split_values[1])

print s.add
```

**Output:**

```
[['mohan', 'ps'], ['gandhi', 'as']]
```

Comment: i specifcally want to use build and build1 both the functions

Comment: Updated snippet.